# undertow - IllegalStateException: UT000021: Session already invalidated

Tags: java, spring-security, wildfly, undertow

Even though session can be taken from request, it seems to be invalidated in undertow's [InMemorySessionManager](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/io/undertow/undertow-core/1.0.14.Final/undertow-core-1.0.14.Final-javadoc.jar-unzip/io/undertow/server/session/InMemorySessionManager.html). Please find the logs:

```
IllegalStateException: UT000021: Session already invalidated
    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.invalidate(InMemorySessionManager.java:375)
    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.invalidate(InMemorySessionManager.java:365)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.invalidate(HttpSessionImpl.java:197)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler.logout(SecurityContextLogoutHandler.java:65)
```

Can we just recheck if the undertow session is invalidated or not before Spring's [SecurityContextLogoutHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/SecurityContextLogoutHandler.html#logout-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-) invalidates the session? I need this IllegalStateException not to occur.